# Ember: insert errors from model into application template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, model, ember-data

I saw the becameError and becameInvalid triggers within the Model Class, for example:

```
//model/car.js
example  import Ember from "ember";
import Model from "ember-data/model";

export default Model.extend({
  becameError() {
    alert('there was an error!');
  },

  becameInvalid(errors) {
    alert(`Record was invalid because: ${errors}`);
  },
});
```

Now when I save the model and my backend returns an error, the alert will be shown. But how can I display the error message within the application template?

Something like:

```
becameError() {
    applcation.set('hasError', true);
  },

//application.hbs
{{#if hasError}}
   <h1>An error has occured!</h1>
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [service](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/applications/services/) for this.

```
//services/error-container.js
...
errors: Ember.A()
...
```

now car model

```
//models/car.js
...
export default Model.extend({
  errorContainer: Ember.inject.service(),
  becameError() {
    alert('there was an error!');
    this.get('errorContainer.errors').pushObjects(this.get('errors'));
  }
...
```

and in application template

```
//application.hbs
{{#if hasError}}
   {{#each errorContainer.errors as |error|}}
      <div>error.message</div>
   {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

and in application controller

```
...
errorContainer: Ember.inject.service(),
hasError: Ember.computed.notEmpty('errorContainer.errors')
...
```

Also you need to take care of clearing removing error object from `errors` too